# Create an iterative function which stops when it is true in r

Tags: r, iteration, geospatial, r-sp

I want to force the *spsample* function to have a specific number of sample size; the *spsample* function makes an approximate sample size:

```
library (sp)
s_size <-1000

data(meuse.riv)
meuse.sr = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(meuse.riv)), "x")))
a<- spsample(meuse.sr, n = s_size, "regular")
length(a)
# 1006

b<- spsample(meuse.sr, n = s_size, "regular")
length(b)
# 998

c<- spsample(meuse.sr, n = s_size, "regular")
length(c)
# 1003
```

Comment: I have solved the problem as follows:

while (length(a)!=s_size <-1000) {
 a<-  spsample(meuse.sr, n = s_size, "regular")
}

If you have another ways to do it let me know.
Thanks

Comment: It's sometimes faster to oversample and throw away the extras:  e.g. ask for 1100, keep the first 1000.  It doesn't matter whether the first call returns 1050 or 1150, you get your 1000 in one call.